# Warning After updating to 2008R2 AD

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, active-directory

We added a new DC server yesturday and we are getting the following issue on the new machine only.

Log Name:      Application
Source:        SceCli
Date:          18/02/2010 11:30:44
Event ID:      1202
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      **
Description:
Security policies were propagated with warning. 0x57 : The parameter is incorrect.

Advanced help for this problem is available on http://support.microsoft.com. Query for "troubleshooting 1202 events".
Event Xml:

  
    
    1202
    3
    0
    0x80000000000000
    
    565
    Application
    **
    
  
  
    0x57 : The parameter is incorrect.

Advanced help for this problem is available on http://support.microsoft.com. Query for "troubleshooting 1202 events".

We are running a 2003 R2 domain and have just added a new 2008 R2 DC. Updated the scheme and everything went well.

The new 2008 R2 DC seems to be running fine apart from this error.

looked in winlogon and found the follow error repeated

Error 50: The request is not supported.
 Configuring some user rights for this account is not supported. Re-attempting configuration by ignoring unsupported operation errors.
  remove SeChangeNotifyPrivilege.
Configuring SeChangeNotifyPrivilege for this account is not supported.
  remove SeImpersonatePrivilege.
Configuring SeImpersonatePrivilege for this account is not supported.
  remove SeCreateGlobalPrivilege.
Configuring SeCreateGlobalPrivilege for this account is not supported.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you update the schema, did you forestprep and domainprep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a conflicting group policy